# Extract specific fields from ReactMarkdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, react-markdown

Hi I'm getting data (a table) as a markdown and displaying it thru ReactMarkdown but i want to extract specific fields lets say I have a markdown like this:

[
{
"type": "markdown",
"data": "| test | **1**    | **2**    | **3**    | **4**    | **5**    | **6**   | **7**   | **8**       | **9**       |\n|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|\n| Test1/ Test2| **Not Needed**    | **Not Needed**    | **Not Needed**    | **Not Needed**    | **Not Needed**    |          |          |          |          |\n| Test3/ Test4|          |          |          |          |          | **Not Needed**    | **Not Needed**    | **Not Needed**    | **Not Needed**    |\n|          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |"
}
]

From this I want to extract the 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 and 9 which are displayed thru ReactMarkdown as `<thead><td>...<td></thead>`

So is there a way with document.querySelector to fetch that specific data or any other way. Any help would be great, thanks in advance

Comment: By "extract" what do you mean? Are you asking how to remove that text from the `data` string so that it doesn't appear in the final table rendered by ReactMarkdown?

Comment: By extract i mean get lets say a new constant which is an array of those elements. Like I mentioned above 1,2,3,4 etc